# How Do I Give An IAM User Permissions To Invoke Only One API Gateway HTTP Endpoint In The CDK?

Tags: amazon-iam, api-gateway

The current AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess `JSON` shows no option for determining which endpoints within the resource the user has permissions to invoke. It shows to be all endpoints.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke",
                "execute-api:ManageConnections"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I narrow it down to specific endpoints? Is there a way do it in the CDK?

I'm looking to have two users, each with their own endpoints they can invoke, but still keeping one API HTTP Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Layout the resources as follows:

```
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage/METHOD_HTTP_VERB/Resource-path"
  ]
```

Go to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html) for more reading.